# How to delete the extra white space of the body height when I move my sections up

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website, and want to add a colorful circle background across sections. However, as I rotate the circles, they add extra heights to the body. It causes the extra white space at the end of my page.

How can I remove those white spaces? Or if anyone have an idea how to add a color background across section to section without adding height to the body?

This is what I've done so far:

```css
.green {
  width: 400rem;
  height: 70rem;
  background-color: rgba(23, 132, 17, 0.2);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position: relative;
  left: -40%;
  bottom: -30rem;
}

.blue {
  width: 400rem;
  height: 70rem;
  background-color: rgba(34, 116, 165, 0.2);
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  position: relative;
  left: -40%;
  bottom: 40rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <h3><span>Supportive Care</span> reduces the rates of re-hospitalization and unnecessary procedures and increases patient satisfaction. It allows patient/family to be more in tune with what’s going on and what choices are available to them.</h3>
    <h3>We develop a plan of care consistent with the patient/family’s cultural, social, religious and spiritual beliefs, review advanced directives and POLST (Physical Orders for Life-sustaining Treatment), discuss prognosis, disease course and realistic
      expectations, and coordinate care with all the physicians on the case.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</section>
```

The circle are .blue and .green. between intro and FAQ sections.

Comment: Can you isolate and share the relevant code that you're adding this background with? please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's tough to see what your end goal is.  The problem is you have bottom: 100rem on your sections.  I'd find a better way to position these.

Comment: I posted the code for the main problem below.

Comment: *"I want to add a colorful circle background across sections"*. As plastic as it may sound, it is impossible to specifically determine what you mean by it. How would the circle look, where should it be placed? What's the relation between a section and the circle's center and/or radius? Should the circle expand to fit the entire viewport or should it be clipped at the end of the section? What happens when you have two sections? What about mobile? And, by far, the most important question: Shouldn't you answer all these questions before you ask yourself (or others) how you can do it technically?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/kgm9p4dh/)?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Oh hell yes. It is the one I'm looking for. It shouldn't add any extra white space right?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu and I'm sorry for the confusion that my question might make. I just tried to recreate it based on the psd file. Your link might be the answer that I'm looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I applied your code but turns out it still appears white space. The white space now is on the right side of the web page, on smaller screen size. It works perfect on desktop screen though.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing.
give your body tag

```
body{
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

or else make a parent of class of you section intro and give those property to it..

Comment: actually you are right .. because of your class green.. it creating white space..but in real.. there is no white space.... use your same code and set the max height of you parent div same to container class using jQuery.. my it work

Comment: Masih, it's not ***"my** class green"*, because I am not the one who asked the question. I just wanted to give you advice on how to avoid downvotes and, in general, provide better answers. Cheers!